# reduce RDD having key as (String,String)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I want to use a ((String,String),BigDecimal) RDD as a PairRDD, so that I can use reduceByKey function. Spark does not recognise the RDD as PairRDD. Is there a way to achieve the reduce function with the RDD.

```
scala> jrdd2
jrdd2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((String, String), java.math.BigDecimal)] = MapPartitionsRDD[33] at map at <console>:30

scala> val jrdd3 = jrdd2.reduceBykey((a,b)=>(a.add(b),1))
<console>:28: error: value reduceBykey is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((String, String), java.math.BigDecimal)]
       val jrdd3 = jrdd2.reduceBykey((a,b)=>(a.add(b),1))
```

Comment: its `.reduceByKey()` not `.reduceBykey()`

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo. Spent 30 minutes trying to solve it. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your `reduceByKey` must return a BigDecimal - not a tuple. Try this instead:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq((("a", "b"), new java.math.BigDecimal(2)), 
                             (("c", "d"), new java.math.BigDecimal(1)), 
                             (("a", "b"), new java.math.BigDecimal(2))))

rdd.reduceByKey(_.add(_))
```

returns

```
((c,d),1)
((a,b),4)
```

Comment: Thanks Glennie. It was just a silly typo in the method name.

Comment: No, your problem - as posted here - is _not_ just a typo. You are returning a `Tuple` instead of a `BigDecimal` which will result in the `value reduceBykey is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((String, String), java.math.BigDecimal)]` error.

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, my code had typo as well as the issue you pointed out. I ended up using combineByKey method.